# What entitlements for paternity leave in a small company in California?

Tags: california, employment

Many small companies California that have no paternity policy and are less than 50 people?

What paid, or unpaid paternity leave entitlements do employees generally have (under federal and California law)?

Update: (from @dw1's links)

- FMLA and CFRA provide job protected leave (but only apply to companies > 50 people, and do no guarantee pay)
- SDI and PFL provide income if time off is taken (but do not, I think, require companies to allow time off -- i.e. you can be fired for taking time off).

Are small companies required to allow male employees ANY time off? (other than sickness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

California has a paid leave program. In order to qualify for disbursements you must make regular contributions to a state insurance fund.

> In 2002, California became the first state in the United States to create the Paid Family Leave (PFL) program – a family leave insurance program that provides income replacement to eligible workers for family caregiving or bonding with a new child. . . . Workers who contribute to the California State Disability Insurance (SDI) fund are entitled to six weeks of partial pay each year while taking time off from work . . . ([Source](http://paidfamilyleave.org/ask-us/what-is-paid-family-leave))

There may also be other opportunities.

> Paid Family Leave provides partial income replacement to you while you are on leave if you have paid into State Disability Insurance (SDI) and you are eligible, but it does not guarantee job protection during your leave. However, you may be eligible for job-protected leave through the federal [Family and Medical Leave Act](http://www.dol.gov/whd/fmla/) (FMLA), the [California Family Rights Act](http://www.dfeh.ca.gov/Publications_CFRADefined.htm) (CFRA) or the California Pregnancy Disability Leave (PDL) law. If you are a union member, you may have the right to job-protected leave through a collective bargaining agreement. ([Source](http://paidfamilyleave.org/ask-us/what-are-my-rights))

Comment: @user48956 We can help tell you what the law is but we can not advise you on the particulars of your case.  you would need to retain an attorney for that type of advice.

Comment: Thanks - have updated my question so that it pertains to generic law. Generically, under California or Federal law, are small companies required to allow male employees any time off in the event of a new child (ignoring sickness, which seems to be covered by other laws).